# how to write this conditions in php

Tags: php, class

hey guys ,  im writing a class and im wondering how i can write a condition statement in this way :

```
$this->referer= (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) ? htmlspecialchars((string) $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) : '';
```

i need to  find my user_id and this is the  usual condtion :

```
    if(is_user($user)){ 
        $cookie=cookiedecode($user);
        $user_id=intval($cookie[0]);
    }
```

and i think it should be something like this  :

```
    $this->user_id = (is_user($user)) ? (cookiedecode($user)) : $cookie[0];
```

but it didnt work

Comment: Why do you try to rewrite it with a conditional expression?

Comment: u mean , i can define my var before i define  user_id in my class !, yeah thats right

Comment: @Gumbo To make it less readable :p

Comment: +1 for Mike , to make it less readable :D

Answer (score 2):

what about this way  :

```
    if(is_user($user)){ 
        $cookie=cookiedecode($user);
        $this->user_id =intval($cookie[0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator should be used sparingly, and only when the logic is simple enough to maintain readability! Get too complex and the shorthand outweighs its usefulness by being difficult to understand.

The ternary operator will only work with one variable assignement at a time. Here is the [manual example](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

```
<?php
// Example usage for: Ternary Operator
$action = (empty($_POST['action'])) ? 'default' : $_POST['action'];

// The above is identical to this if/else statement
if (empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = 'default';
} else {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
}
```

Your example

```
$this->user_id = (is_user($user)) ? (cookiedecode($user)) : $cookie[0];
```

will assign the user_id to `cookiedecode($user)` if `is_user()` returns true, or to `$cookie[0]` if not.

In light of this:

### you should keep your existing code structure!!

Comment: but my friend , the example u gave me is exactly what i used and shown in my question , i tried that statement but didnt work for me , and return 0 
$this->user_id = (is_user($user)) ? (cookiedecode($user)) : $cookie[0];

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(is_user($user)){ 
        $cookie=cookiedecode($user);
        $this->user_id =intval($cookie[0]);
    }

   I didn't see any ELSE statement in your code and i don't understand on why do you want to use short form of conditional statement.
```